# Двумерный вектор

Tags: c++, fft

Пытаюсь организовать двумерное FFT. Нужно сделать именно через двумерный вектор. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так с этим кодом

```
const int RR = 8;
const int CC = 8;
vector<vector<complex<double>> > matrix;
for (int i = 0; i < RR; i++)
{
    vector<complex<double>> myvector;
    for (int j = 0; j < CC; j++)
    {
        complex<double> tempVal = { 1,0 };
        myvector.push_back(tempVal);
    }
    matrix.push_back(myvector);
}

for (int i = 0; i < RR; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < CC; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }

    cout << '\n';
}
cout << endl;


fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(
    RR,
    CC,
    (fftw_complex*) matrix.data(),
    (fftw_complex*) matrix.data(),
    FFTW_FORWARD,
    FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(plan);
fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

for (int i = 0; i < RR; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < CC; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }

    cout << '\n';
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что с ним что-то не так? Получаете неправильный выход, ошибки? Приведите это в вопросе с помощью кнопки править

Comment: При исполнении fftw_execute(plan) вылезает ошибка.( Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.**this** было 0xCDCDCDCD.) Похоже ему не нравится как организован двумерный вектор, т.к. с одномерным вектором все работает и с двумерным массивом тоже.

Answer (score 1):

FFTW работает с массивом или с указателем на **непрерывную** область данных. Организация массива описана в документации (в частности, массив должен быть чуть больше, чем произведение размерностей)

Однако строки двумерного вектора хранятся в **разных** областях памяти, поэтому при своей работе FFTW попадает в чужие области памяти - вот и нарушение доступа.

Используйте одномерный вектор, либо при использовании двумерного вектора делайте раздельные одномерные Фурье по строкам и по столбцам - для второй части FFTW использовать не получится без перепаковки данных.

Можно использовать свою реализацию FFT с любой, какой захочется, организацией входных данных, если скорость не так уж важна.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Так я и думал что проблемы с памятью. Но все еще не ясно как тогда считать. Мне надо остаться именно в векторах. Не могли бы Вы если не сложно дать пример решения, так чтобы на входе был двумерный вектор и на выходе тоже он. P.S.: скорость крайне важна, поэтому я пытаюсь FFTW использовать. Странно что он не дружелюбен к двумерным векторам, это ведь ключевой элемент вычисления в матрицах, по типу матлаба.

Comment: FFTW нацелен на максимальную оптимизацию, которая достигается при работе с единым куском памяти. Возможно, найдутся другие библиотеки для FFT, которые способны работать с двумерными векторами, но самые быстрые используют низкоуровневый интерфейс (обычно указатель на область памяти). Переключение страниц памяти, неизбежное при использовании построчного хранения, замедляет доступ. А классический метод c одномерными FFT пробовали? Скорости не хватает?

Comment: Вообще перепаковка данных в одномерный массив и обратно - менее затратная операция, чем FFТ, поэтому, если скорость важна, стоит это делать

Comment: одномерный FFTW работает прекрасно и на векторе и на массиве, с этим проблем нет. Если я правильно понял Вас, то мне надо разложить двумерный вектор в одномерный вектор (ну или массив), взять одномерное FFTW и перегнать обратно в двумерный вектор? А по математике это и будет двумерное Фурье?

Comment: Если перевести все данные в одномерный вектор или массив, то можно делать двумерное Фурье, т.к. в этом случае все данные будут лежать в памяти последовательно. Только прочитайте об организации данных для _2d - там есть тонкость, которую я уже отмечал

Comment: Большое спасибо! Попробую так сделать, надеюсь получится!